# Remove incorrect quotes from generated SQL files

Tags: regex

I have 100000 lines as such:-

```
/** http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/8720175/vessel:SEMUTIK_NO_1 **/INSERT INTO `vessel`(id,name,`imo`, `flag`, `type`, `speed`, `callsign`, `tonnage`, `length`, `deadweight`, `year`, `status`, `draught`,mmsi) VALUES (27797,'SEMUTIK_NO_1'','8720175','-','Fishing Vessel','N/A','-','152','0m x 0m','0','1974','Active','0m',-8720175)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^
```

I've generated these queries and saved it in various files.However now i found that there is a problem with the query and it will be taking me a lot of time to regenerate the query.See the name value in the query, there is an extra  quote. I wanna know a regex to find and remove it, mostly in Java or even php.

Comment: Consider editing your question... honestly, it's a bit hard to read.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: i was thinking of using php because i already know how to match the mistake. Sorry for the way i asked the question. Will php be better or java

Comment: Why use a coding language when you can use an IDE. I suggest you have a look at @peterm's answer

Comment: I cannot use find and replace because I have other query in the same file that has '' as entry.

Comment: Please don't add random tags. Which *tool* will be running the regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

Just open your file with queries in a text editor of your choice (Sublime, TextMate, vim, what have you) and issue find and replace `'',` for `',`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
String str = "INSERT INTO vessel(id,name,imo, flag, type, speed, callsign, \n" +
    "tonnage, length, deadweight, year, status, draught,mmsi) \n" +
    "VALUES (27797,'SEMUTIK_NO_1'','8720175','-','Fishing Vessel',\n" +
    "'N/A','-','152','0m x 0m','0','1974','Active','0m',-8720175)";


System.out.println(str.replaceAll("''", "'"));
```